# How can I call a PL/Perl function from another PL/Perl function?

Tags: perl, postgresql, plperl

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plperl
    AS $$
        return 'foo';
$$;

CREATE FUNCTION foobar() RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plperl
    AS $$
        return foo() . 'bar';
$$;
```

I'm trying to compose results using multiple functions, but when I call `foobar()` I get an empty result.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-missing.html):

> PL/Perl functions cannot call each other directly (because they are anonymous subroutines inside Perl).

The solution appears to be either calling the function as a postgres function (using spi_query) or you can put references to your functions in the globally available hash `%_SHARED` as shown [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-global.html)